# How many people need to review each queue to remove the post from queue?

Tags: support, reviewing

I've been reviewing a lot of suggested edits recently and sometimes there is a red dot by it meaning that there are a lot of posts in that queue. But after I go through and complete them all I notice the red dot is still there. I assume that this means that it takes more than one person to clear a queue so-

How many people need to review a post in each queue to remove that item from queue?

Comment: [Should I blame caching?](https://shouldiblamecaching.com/)

Comment: Between 1 and 9, generally. Each queue is different. Suggested Edits need 2 approves or rejects for it to be accepted/declined (so up to 3 people need to review). Although this can be short-ciruited by editing the post yourself (i.e. 'Improve' or 'Reject and Edit'), so it has a minimum of 1 reviewer.

Comment: Because five names are mentioned upon closing, I assume it's five persons for the closing queues. I've always assumed the other queues (except for suggested edits) need the same amount (unless an administrator comes by).